# Use left join but the value no showing?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table, `game_jnship_equip_list` is store equipment basic info, `game_jnship_equip` is store for what does player have.

Here is `game_jnship_equip_list` data:

```
+--------+----------------+----------+----------+
| ID     | desc           | name     | type     |
+--------+----------------+----------+----------+
| 1      | hello_weapon   | weapon   | 1        |
| 2      | hello_shirt    | shirt    | 2        |
| 3      | hell_weapon    | Hweapon  | 1        |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Here is `game_jnship_equip` data:

```
+------+----------+--------------+------------+------------+
| ID   | userid   | itemcode     | atfigure   | eposition  |
+------+----------+--------------+------------+------------+
| 1    | 1        | 1            | 100        | 1          |
| 2    | 1        | 2            | 500        | 2          |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

And I query as below:

```
$quequip = DB::query("SELECT t1.*,t2.name AS weaponame, t2.edesc AS weapondesc, t3.atfigure AS atkbonus, t4.name AS shirtname, t4.edesc AS shirtdesc  FROM ".DB::table('game_jnship_equip')." t1 LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('game_jnship_equip_list')." t2 ON (t1.itemid = t2.id AND t1.eposition = '1') LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('game_jnship_equip')." t3 ON (t2.type = t3.eposition) LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('game_jnship_equip_list')." t4 ON (t1.itemid = t4.id AND t1.eposition = '2') WHERE t1.uid = 'userid' AND t1.status = '1'"); 
$ruequip = DB::fetch($quequip);
```

But, I only can get value as below:

```
$ruequip['weaponame'] = weapon;
$ruequip['weapodesc'] = hello_weapon;
$ruequip['atkbonus'] = 100;
```

Then about the `t4` all blank.

```
$ruequip['shirtname'] = ;
$ruequip['shirtdesc'] = ;
```

I want it to show value as below:

```
$ruequip['shirtname'] = shirt;
$ruequip['shirtdesc'] = hello_shirt;
```

So how to fix this? and my `DB::query` function, it cannot allow `DB::query(SELECT * FROM xxxx (SELECT * FROM))`, means 2 select inside 1 `DB::query`, system will reject by safety issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with conditional aggregation using `CASE EXPRESSION` instead of 3 left joins :

```
SELECT s.id,s.userid,s.itemcode,s.atfigure,s.eposition,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.eposition = 1 THEN s.desc END) as weap_desc,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.eposition = 1 THEN s.name END) as weap_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.eposition = 2 THEN s.desc END) as shirt_desc,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.eposition = 2 THEN s.name END) as shirt_name
FROM (SELECT t.id,t.userid,t.itemcode,t.atfigure,t.eposition,t2.desc,t2.name
      FROM  ".DB::table('game_jnship_equip')." t
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ".DB::table('game_jnship_equip_list')." t2
       ON(t1.itemid = t2.id AND t.eposition = t2.type) )s
GROUP BY s.user_id
```

Comment: sorry, my `DB::query` function is not allow 2 `select * from` function for safety issue

Answer (score 1):

Why not a union ?

```
SELECT
  list.id as weaponid,
  list.desc as weapondesc,
  list.name as weaponame,
  quip.atfigure as atkbonus
from ".DB::table('game_jnship_equip_list')." as list
  left join ".DB::table('game_jnship_equip')." as quip
    on (quip.itemcode = list.id)
Where list.type = 1
UNION
SELECT
  list.id as shirtid,
  list.desc as shirtdesc,
  list.name as shirtname,
  quip.atfigure as atkbonus
from elist as list
  left join equip as quip
    on (quip.itemcode = list.id)
Where list.type = 2
```

This will get you a specific type 2 and a specific type 1. I didn't added the other user and position conditions but you can do that yourself.

Comment: Why would you do this? its the same as 1 select with `WHERE list.type in(1,2)` . Not to talk about the fact that his requirement was having this columns next to each other, not as separate rows.